# TeamCity Artifacts

Tags: teamcity-9.0

Combine Destination folder path in Teamcity artifacts

e.g

```
Source/abc/Comm/bin/Release => package.%system.Build_Number%.zip!/Link1 
Source/abc/Comm/bin/Release => package.%system.Build_Number%.zip/Link2
```

I need to combine the destination

Comment: You are saying destination, have you declared this as a configuration parameter ?. Then you can just reference it.

Answer (score 0):

Under Artifact Paths put
+:%project_dist_dir% => package.%system.Build_Number%.zip

Then everything will be combined into the zip file.